# Proving that a dense set in a poset by Zorn's lemma have a maximal antichain as a subset

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

So I am little confused here; Zorn's lemma says that if every chain has a supremum in a poset one defines, then the poset must have a maximal element. My question is, how does this lead to the proof that a dense set in a poset by Zorn's lemma have a maximal antichain as a subset of the dense set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $D$ is a dense subset of a poset $P$.  Define $Q$ to be the family of all antichains of $P$ made up of elements of $D$, ordered by inclusion.  By Zorn's Lemma $Q$ has a maximal element, call it $A$.  In particular this means that for every $y \in D$ either $y \in A$ or $A \cup \{ y \}$ is not an antichain, which implies that $y$ is compatible with some element of $A$; in either case $y$ is compatible with some element of $A$.

To show that $A$ is actually a maximal antichain in $P$ it suffices to show that every $x \in P$ is compatible with an element of $A$.  Given $p \in P$a s $D$ is dense in $P$ there is a $y \in D$ with $y \leq x$.  By the above there is an $a \in A$ such that $a$ and $y$ are compatible.  It follows that $x$ and $a$ are compatible.

Comment: How does it follow from $a,y$ compatible that $x,a$ are compatible? It may be that $a\ge y\le x$ but $a,x$ are incomparable. This whole construction seems flawed: Let $P=\{0,a,b\}$ where $a\ge 0\le b$, and let $D=\{0,a\}$. $D$ *does* have a subset which is a maximal antichain, but not all maximal antichains in $D$ are such. The maximal antichain $\{a\}$ of $D$ is not a maximal antichain of $P$.